# Oracle query to display missing results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have SQL query below to show the person's name, count between date range. It shows the results as below:

```
DAY           NAME           count_person 
04-MAY-2020   person_1       220
06-MAY-2020   person_1       30
```

I would like my results to show as below if the name is missing for that date

```
DAY           NAME           count_person 
01-MAY-2020   person_1       0
02-MAY-2020   person_1       0
03-MAY-2020   person_1       220
04-MAY-2020   person_1       30
'
'
'
31-MAY-2020   person_1       0
```

Below is my sql query:

```
SELECT  TRUNC(AN.DATE_CREATED) DAY,  AN.NAME, COUNT(AN.NAME) count_person 
FROM 
    person AN 
WHERE 
    TRUNC(AN.DATE_CREATED) >= '01-MAY-20' 
    AND TRUNC(AN.DATE_CREATED) <= '31-MAY-20' 
    GROUP BY TRUNC(AN.DATE_CREATED), AN.NAME
```

Thanks for the solution, I have a modification for my output
The output to be shown like below:

```
DAY           NAME           count_person 
01-MAY-2020   person_1       0
02-MAY-2020   person_1       0
03-MAY-2020   person_1       220
04-MAY-2020   person_1       30
05-MAY-2020   person_1       30
'
'
15-MAY-2020   person_1       12
16-MAY-2020   person_1       12
'
'
31-MAY-2020   person_1       30
```

meaning if on the particular date I have zero count then it should take the count from the previous date and if it's non zero then it leave it? I tried using lead but the logic doesn't work to take the previous value.

Comment: Your dates and values don't seem to quite match; even more so after your edit. I think I've understood what you mean, but it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can produce all dates from a date range using a recursive CTE, and then perform a left join with the table you already have.

For example:

```
with
range (d) as (
  select date '2020-05-01' from dual
 union all
  select d + 1
  from range
  where d < date '2020-05-31'
)
select
  r.d, 
  coalesce(p.name, 
    (select name from person order by name fetch next 1 rows only)
  ) as person, 
  coalesce(p.count, 0) as count
from range r
left join person p on p.day = r.d
order by r.d
```

Result:

```
 D          PERSON    COUNT 
 ---------- --------- ----- 
 01-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 02-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 03-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 04-MAY-20  person_1  220   
 05-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 06-MAY-20  person_1  30    
 07-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 08-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 09-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 10-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 11-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 12-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 13-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 14-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 15-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 16-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 17-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 18-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 19-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 20-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 21-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 22-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 23-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 24-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 25-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 26-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 27-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 28-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 29-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 30-MAY-20  person_1  0     
 31-MAY-20  person_1  0
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=31355eb1fde44d35dcdb38adb2430aec).

Comment: hi, thank you for the solution. I have updated the question, my output requirement is changed

Comment: @shanky I would suggest you ask a separate question with the new requirements. By the way, where does `12` come from? Also, why does 4-may have 30 in it?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the existing data.  You also need to generate a count, so aggregation is involved as well.

@TheImpaler's answer is correct . . . for one person.  But for all people:

```
with days (d) as (
      select date '2020-05-01' from dual
      union all
      select d + interval '1' day
      from days
      where d < date '2020-05-31'
     )
select d.day, p.name, count(p.name) as count_person 
from days d cross join
     (select distinct p.name from person) n left join 
     person p
     on trunc(p.date_created) = d.d and
        p.name = n.name
group by d.day, p.name
order by p.name, d.day;
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea to @TheImpaler, at least to generate the individual days; but you also need to get the relevant names, and use both in an outer join to your person table, e.g.:

```
with days (day) as (
  select date '2020-05-01' from dual
  union all
  select day + 1 from days where day < last_day(day)
),
names (name) as (
  select distinct name from person
  -- possibly only within the target month?
)
select d.day, n.name, count(p.name) as count_person
from days d
cross join names n
left join person p on p.name = n.name
and p.date_created >= d.day
and p.date_created < d.day + 1
group by d.day, n.name
order by d.day, n.name
```

The recursive days CTE starts at the first of a month and gets all days for that month, without having to specify the end date - though you can still do that if you prefer of course.

The names CTE gets all names from the target table; but you might actually want to get them from another table, or use a fixed name, or a collection of names; or might only want names that have any data in that month. It's unclear if that needs to be restricted.

Those are then cross-joined to get every person on every day. The result of that is then outer-joined to your real table based on both the names and the date, using a range instead of truncating.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d3cf3b6696e721cc26b80c9f73c448de) showing the result with data simulating your current output; and with an extra row for another person, showing each person gets a row for every day.

---

> if on the particular date I have zero count then it should take the count from the previous date and if it's non zero then it leave it

You can use `last_value()`, with a bit of manipulation:

```
with days (day) as (
  select date '2020-05-01' from dual
  union all
  select day + 1 from days where day < last_day(day)
),
names (name) as (
  select distinct name from person
  -- possibly only within the target month?
)
select d.day, n.name,
  coalesce(
    last_value(nullif(count(p.name),0) ignore nulls)
      over (partition by n.name order by d.day), 0) as count_person
from days d
cross join names n
left join person p on p.name = n.name
and p.date_created >= d.day
and p.date_created < d.day + 1
group by d.day, n.name
order by n.name, d.day
```

The `nullif(count(...), 0)` treats a zero-count as null; `last_value()` ignores nulls so gets the last not-null value (including the current row); and as the first three days would have no not-null values to use, `coalesce(..., 0)` converts those to zero.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa912e964b26a8877be9652f06ee6576)